# Magento version upgrade without using SSH

Tags: php, magento

Good afternoon all

I want to upgrade magento version 1.3.x to1.7.x ,without using SSH. Is there any way to upgrade without using SSH. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sources](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/upgrade_using_magento_connect)

- in the admin go to System/Magento Connect/Magento Connect Manager
- Paste magento-core/Mage_All_Latest into Paste extension key to install:, then click Install
- You may get a message like this(and more) in the pear window below
- magento-core/Mage_All_Latest requires package “magento-core/Mage_Core_Modules” (version >= 1.1.8, version ⇐ 1.2, excluded versions: 1.2), installed version is 1.1.6
- At the far right of Manage Existing Extensions click Check for Upgrades
- Rows of packages with available upgrades will now be yellow.
- Chose the latest version in every rows select.
- Now click Commit Changes.
- Now again, paste magento-core/Mage_All_Latest into Paste extension key to install:, then click Install.